# LightSwitch HTML Client - How to add global menu

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

Is it possible to add global menu items like in desktop client LightSwitch? Or something simular to it... How, or better question is, where can I do it?

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer on microsoft Lightswitch forums so I'll just briefly wrote what I have found out.

This isn't supported out from the box. Best solution I found is to create table in DB. Then we should create attributes:

> ie. "screen name", "screen display name", "picture" as menu icon, and maybe some boolean as "can run" method, then you could put tile control on startup screen to become "menu"

More details about this suggestions can be found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/1695aaea-ece8-4050-8850-7971aa50af50

Thanks goes to Kivito from MS forums...

Another way is to create customchrome.js and then handle everything from JS. This is just my idea but I haven't tried it because I didn't have enough time to experiment. For a few screens is much faster to just add command buttons on each screen.